# Is it possible to disable USB port with known physical location?

Tags: 18.04, usb, kernel, webcam, microphone

I have a laptop with faulty LCD-panel cable. This cable is routed to LCD-panel and web-cam with microphone. The LCD-panel works normally, but webcam and microphone are faulty. I do not plan to visit repair, so I hope to get software based solution. Really I do not use this webcam and have bluetooth handset for mic replacement.

Currently I know that webcam is at `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5`.
I want do blacklist this port.

If it matters, `lsusb` says currently the following about this device:

```
Bus 002 Device 053: ID 04f2:b330 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Asus 720p CMOS webcam
```

and *Device 053* has an increment.

It floods syslog with messages like

- *usb 2-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 29 using ehci-pci*
- *usb 2-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error -71*
- *usb 2-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 23*.

Without `uvcvideo` driver blacklisting it floods the `uvcdynctrl-udev.log` file:

```
$ ls -alh /var/log/uvcdynctrl-udev.log 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8,1G Apr 17 18:20 /var/log/uvcdynctrl-udev.log
```

So I have already blacklisted `uvcvideo` kernel driver by placing `blacklist uvcvideo` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-uvc.conf`. But this single measure does not help.

How should I blacklist faulty internal USB port with connected webcam completely?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with just a couple of commands in the terminal:

1. Disable the USB port:

   ```
   echo disabled | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/wakeup
   ```
2. Remove power from the port:

   ```
   echo suspend | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/level
   ```

In the event this doesn’t work, a `udev` rule may be necessary:

1. Create a new file in `/lib/udev/rules.d` using a text editor of your choice. For example:

   ```
   sudo vi /lib/udev/rules.d/20-block-webcam.rules
   ```
2. Revoke authorization for the webcam to be accessed:

   ```
   # Chicony Webcam
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="b330", ATTR{authorized}="0"
   ```

   <sub>*Looks like the output of* `lsusb` ***did** matter*</sub>
3. Reboot

---

From comments:

Also it then maybe fixed by `echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.5/authorized` as per https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/authorization.txt .
Put `echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.5/authorized` to `/etc/rc.local`.

Also, the port can be disabled completely (kernel will stop enumerating of any devices connected to this port, but will keep power on port) using the command like following (this command disables the USB port 1-6 on my system):

`echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/1-0:1.0/usb1-port6/disable`

Comment: I have already read something that you are going to recommend. The first command works, but not enough. The second fails - `echo suspend | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/level` it returns `suspend` with `tee: /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/level: Invalid argument`. How should we fix the second command?

Comment: This command will remove power from *just* the camera, which may get you closer to where you want to go: `echo suspend | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1/power/level` 

Comment: It says `Invalid argument` too. Do we have other flags in sysfs?

Comment: Updated answer to use a `udev` rule. It’s an older technique, but should work 

Comment: Great! Also it then maybe fixed by `echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1/authorized` as per https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/authorization.txt . I put `echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1/authorized` to `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: I’ll have to update my “Notebook of Ubuntu Cheats” for that 

Comment: Note that the "level" file is deprecated since 2.6.35 and replaced by a "control" file, but that no longer supports the "suspend" value since 2.6.32. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.0/driver-api/usb/power-management.html#the-user-interface-for-dynamic-pm

Comment: @matigo do you know if it is possible to turn off a Wacom touch device but not the stylus/tablet devices? please see my question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/756097/extra-udev-rule-to-keep-wacom-stylus-turned-on-while-disabling-touchscreen-libi

Answer (score 2):

I ended up here twice having the same issue with the fingerprint reader but the other options didn't work as the `suspend` was not the answer.

What I ended up doing was starting  `powertop` and using their `tunables` features to see how they got rid of the device consuming power.

In my case, the offender was `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 27c6:5395 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader`

So using this command taken from `powertop` it works

`echo "auto" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-7/power/control`