# Ubuntu USB port fried, now it won't suspend

Tags: 20.04, usb

my problem is really specific I think. I've spend countless hours trying to remedy it, but to no avail. So this is my problem, I own a Razer Blade 15, have Ubuntu 20.04 installed, yesterday I fried one of my USB ports (I was dumb and fried the damn thing). Now, everytime I close the lid, and the computer tries suspending, it doesn't. Syslog says it's a problem with USB2,

```
PM: Device usb2 failed to suspend async: error -16
```

The fans continue running and when I open the lid back up, it boots up instantly to the lockscreen.

Attempted solutions:
I've tried many things to fix it, I've tried running:

```
echo 'disabled' > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/wakeup
echo 'on' > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/control
echo '-1' > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/autosuspend_delay_ms
echo 'disabled' > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/async
```

I've also tried going to /proc/acpi/awake and disabling XHC, which didn't work, then I disabled every single one and still, the problem persisted. I am not super experienced in Linux, having used it as my primary driver for only 2 weeks now. I can't see myself going back to Windows now, Linux is just so much superior. I'd really appretiate any help, since to be honest this is gamebreaking.

[System info](http://titan.csit.rmit.edu.au/%7Es3751262/hardinfo_report.html)

Syslog

```
Aug  9 00:11:42 Penguin-Rager systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Succeeded.
Aug  9 00:11:44 Penguin-Rager PackageKit: get-updates transaction /1766_eedaacee from uid 1000 finished with success after 474ms
Aug  9 00:11:45 Penguin-Rager systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
Aug  9 00:11:46 Penguin-Rager systemd-timesyncd[1083]: Initial synchronization to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager NetworkManager[1153]: <info>  [1628431908.6699] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager NetworkManager[1153]: <info>  [1628431908.6701] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager NetworkManager[1153]: <info>  [1628431908.6706] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager NetworkManager[1153]: <info>  [1628431908.6708] device (wlo1): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager whoopsie[3528]: [00:11:48] offline
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager dbus-daemon[1152]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=0 pid=1153 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager dbus-daemon[1152]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   38.943793] wlo1: deauthenticating from 70:0b:01:1b:99:0e by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager wpa_supplicant[1199]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=70:0b:01:1b:99:0e reason=3 locally_generated=1
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager NetworkManager[1153]: <warn>  [1628431908.6932] sup-iface[0x55aff1ada920,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager NetworkManager[1153]: <info>  [1628431908.6934] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager NetworkManager[1153]: <info>  [1628431908.6937] device (wlo1): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager avahi-daemon[1144]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::84ba:7102:480f:7180 on wlo1.
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager avahi-daemon[1144]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address fe80::84ba:7102:480f:7180.
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager avahi-daemon[1144]: Interface wlo1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager NetworkManager[1153]: <info>  [1628431908.7294] dhcp4 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager NetworkManager[1153]: <info>  [1628431908.7294] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed bound -> done
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager NetworkManager[1153]: <info>  [1628431908.7298] dhcp6 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager NetworkManager[1153]: <info>  [1628431908.7299] dhcp6 (wlo1): state changed unknown -> done
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager avahi-daemon[1144]: Withdrawing address record for 10.0.0.1 on wlo1.
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager avahi-daemon[1144]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv4 with address 10.0.0.1.
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager avahi-daemon[1144]: Interface wlo1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager NetworkManager[1153]: <info>  [1628431908.7372] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager NetworkManager[1153]: <info>  [1628431908.7415] device (tun0): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager nm-openvpn[3392]: event_wait : Interrupted system call (code=4)
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager nm-openvpn[3392]: SIGTERM received, sending exit notification to peer
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager nm-openvpn[3392]: write UDP: Network is unreachable (code=101)
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager wpa_supplicant[1199]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-100
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager nm-dispatcher[9478]: run-parts: failed to stat component /etc/network/if-post-down.d/avahi-daemon: No such file or directory
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager NetworkManager[1153]: <info>  [1628431908.7480] vpn-connection[0x55aff1b920f0,7d64999f-1a82-41a4-b281-987a6837b38f,"Sydney",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager NetworkManager[1153]: <info>  [1628431908.7481] vpn-connection[0x55aff1b920f0,7d64999f-1a82-41a4-b281-987a6837b38f,"Sydney",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager wpa_supplicant[1199]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlo1 disabled_11b_rates=0
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager nm-dispatcher[9483]: run-parts: failed to stat component /etc/network/if-post-down.d/avahi-daemon: No such file or directory
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager nm-dispatcher[9488]: run-parts: failed to stat component /etc/network/if-post-down.d/avahi-daemon: No such file or directory
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager logger[9513]: <13>Aug  9 00:11:48 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Aug  9 00:11:48 Penguin-Rager wpa_supplicant[1199]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlo1 disabled_11b_rates=0
Aug  9 00:11:49 Penguin-Rager PackageKit: get-updates transaction /1767_babddbdc from uid 1000 finished with success after 421ms
Aug  9 00:11:49 Penguin-Rager nm-openvpn[3392]: SIGTERM[soft,exit-with-notification] received, process exiting
Aug  9 00:11:50 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   41.191957] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
Aug  9 00:11:50 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   41.191961] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Succeeded.
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system suspend actions.
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager systemd-sleep[10005]: Suspending system...
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   41.353334] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   41.366785] Filesystems sync: 0.013 seconds
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   41.496695] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   41.499031] OOM killer disabled.
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   41.499032] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   41.500423] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   41.542602] PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_suspend+0x0/0x20 returns -16
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   41.542617] PM: Device usb2 failed to suspend async: error -16
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   41.867721] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   41.992649] acpi LNXPOWER:06: Turning OFF
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   41.992695] acpi LNXPOWER:02: Turning OFF
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   41.992824] OOM killer enabled.
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   41.992826] Restarting tasks ... done.
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   42.018211] thermal thermal_zone7: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   42.077907] PM: suspend exit
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   42.077958] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Aug  9 00:11:51 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   42.081437] Filesystems sync: 0.003 seconds
Aug  9 00:11:55 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   42.093631] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
Aug  9 00:11:55 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   42.095867] OOM killer disabled.
Aug  9 00:11:55 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   42.095868] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 1.107 seconds) done.
Aug  9 00:11:55 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   43.187673] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Aug  9 00:11:55 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   43.209764] PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_suspend+0x0/0x20 returns -16
Aug  9 00:11:55 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   43.209782] PM: Device usb2 failed to suspend async: error -16
Aug  9 00:11:55 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   44.866318] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
Aug  9 00:11:55 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   46.106266] OOM killer enabled.
Aug  9 00:11:55 Penguin-Rager xdg-desktop-por[3954]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list
Aug  9 00:11:55 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   46.106269] Restarting tasks ... done.
Aug  9 00:11:55 Penguin-Rager appimagelauncherd[3604]: Directories to watch disappeared, unintegrating AppImages formerly found in there
Aug  9 00:11:55 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   46.123238] thermal thermal_zone7: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
Aug  9 00:11:56 Penguin-Rager systemd-sleep[10005]: Failed to suspend system. System resumed again: Device or resource busy
Aug  9 00:11:56 Penguin-Rager kernel: [   46.179514] PM: suspend exit
Aug  9 00:11:56 Penguin-Rager systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug  9 00:11:56 Penguin-Rager systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug  9 00:11:56 Penguin-Rager systemd[1]: Failed to start Suspend.
Aug  9 00:11:56 Penguin-Rager systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Suspend.
Aug  9 00:11:56 Penguin-Rager systemd[1]: suspend.target: Job suspend.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Aug  9 00:11:56 Penguin-Rager systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Aug  9 00:11:56 Penguin-Rager systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system resume actions...
Aug  9 00:11:56 Penguin-Rager suspend: nvidia-resume.service
Aug  9 00:11:56 Penguin-Rager logger[11220]: <13>Aug  9 00:11:56 suspend: nvidia-resume.service
Aug  9 00:11:56 Penguin-Rager NetworkManager[1153]: <info>  [1628431916.4867] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Aug  9 00:11:56 Penguin-Rager NetworkManager[1153]: <info>  [1628431916.4868] device (wlo1): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 00:11:56 Penguin-Rager systemd[1]: nvidia-resume.service: Succeeded.
Aug  9 00:11:56 Penguin-Rager systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system resume actions.
Aug  9 00:11:56 Penguin-Rager acpid: client 3073[0:0] has disconnected
Aug  9 00:11:56 Penguin-Rager acpid: client connected from 3073[0:0]
Aug  9 00:11:56 Penguin-Rager acpid: 1 client rule loaded
```

**UPDATE**

I've still been tinkering around and trying to fix it, and I've come to one thing that does give some sort of result. When I run

```
sudo bash -c "echo 0000:00:14.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind"
```

then I lose the ability to access usb ports, and my keyboard stops responding, but when I shut the lid, the system sleeps like it normally should. I turned on udevadm monitor and unbinded 0000:00:14.0. It resulted in

```
KERNEL[1194.677419] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-0:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[1194.677460] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-0:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[1194.677506] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2 (usb)
KERNEL[1194.677537] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2 (usb)
KERNEL[1194.677797] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:046D:C07D.0002/input/input25/mouse2 (input)
UDEV  [1194.679243] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-0:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1194.680046] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:046D:C07D.0002/input/input25/mouse2 (input)
UDEV  [1194.680293] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-0:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1194.681308] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2 (usb)
UDEV  [1194.682031] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2 (usb)
KERNEL[1194.707697] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:046D:C07D.0002/input/input25/event21 (input)
UDEV  [1194.708748] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:046D:C07D.0002/input/input25/event21 (input)
KERNEL[1194.723609] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:046D:C07D.0002/input/input25 (input)
KERNEL[1194.723740] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:046D:C07D.0002/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
KERNEL[1194.723776] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:046D:C07D.0002 (hid)
KERNEL[1194.723805] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:046D:C07D.0002 (hid)
KERNEL[1194.723830] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[1194.723862] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1194.724690] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:046D:C07D.0002/input/input25 (input)
UDEV  [1194.724730] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:046D:C07D.0002/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
UDEV  [1194.725584] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:046D:C07D.0002 (hid)
UDEV  [1194.726251] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:046D:C07D.0002 (hid)
UDEV  [1194.727370] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1194.728464] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[1194.787772] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:046D:C07D.0003/input/input26/event22 (input)
UDEV  [1194.788984] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:046D:C07D.0003/input/input26/event22 (input)
KERNEL[1194.823649] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:046D:C07D.0003/input/input26 (input)
UDEV  [1194.824749] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:046D:C07D.0003/input/input26 (input)
KERNEL[1194.859691] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:046D:C07D.0003/input/input27/event23 (input)
UDEV  [1194.861217] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:046D:C07D.0003/input/input27/event23 (input)
KERNEL[1194.887692] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:046D:C07D.0003/input/input27 (input)
UDEV  [1194.888864] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:046D:C07D.0003/input/input27 (input)
KERNEL[1194.915566] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:046D:C07D.0003/input/input28/event24 (input)
UDEV  [1194.916622] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:046D:C07D.0003/input/input28/event24 (input)
KERNEL[1194.943738] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:046D:C07D.0003/input/input28 (input)
KERNEL[1194.943790] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/usbmisc/hiddev0 (usbmisc)
KERNEL[1194.943812] remove   /class/usbmisc (class)
KERNEL[1194.943884] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:046D:C07D.0003/hidraw/hidraw2 (hidraw)
KERNEL[1194.943921] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:046D:C07D.0003 (hid)
KERNEL[1194.943951] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:046D:C07D.0003 (hid)
KERNEL[1194.943980] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[1194.944012] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[1194.944122] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4 (usb)
KERNEL[1194.944156] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4 (usb)
KERNEL[1194.944307] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/video4linux/video0 (video4linux)
KERNEL[1194.944403] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/video4linux/video1 (video4linux)
UDEV  [1194.945112] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:046D:C07D.0003/input/input28 (input)
UDEV  [1194.945197] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/usbmisc/hiddev0 (usbmisc)
UDEV  [1194.945746] remove   /class/usbmisc (class)
UDEV  [1194.946387] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:046D:C07D.0003/hidraw/hidraw2 (hidraw)
UDEV  [1194.947549] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:046D:C07D.0003 (hid)
UDEV  [1194.948318] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:046D:C07D.0003 (hid)
UDEV  [1194.949452] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [1194.950546] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [1194.950828] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/video4linux/video1 (video4linux)
UDEV  [1194.951026] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/video4linux/video0 (video4linux)
UDEV  [1194.952016] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4 (usb)
UDEV  [1194.953194] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4 (usb)
KERNEL[1194.987791] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/input/input37/event31 (input)
UDEV  [1194.988886] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/input/input37/event31 (input)
KERNEL[1195.055653] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/input/input37 (input)
KERNEL[1195.055687] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/media0 (media)
KERNEL[1195.055777] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[1195.055805] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[1195.055823] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[1195.055841] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[1195.055883] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/video4linux/video2 (video4linux)
KERNEL[1195.055937] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/video4linux/video3 (video4linux)
UDEV  [1195.056783] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/media0 (media)
UDEV  [1195.056940] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/input/input37 (input)
UDEV  [1195.057272] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [1195.058409] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1195.058452] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [1195.059590] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1195.060562] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/video4linux/video3 (video4linux)
UDEV  [1195.060856] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/video4linux/video2 (video4linux)
KERNEL[1195.087692] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/input/input38/event256 (input)
UDEV  [1195.088810] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/input/input38/event256 (input)
KERNEL[1195.135988] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/input/input38 (input)
KERNEL[1195.136022] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/media1 (media)
KERNEL[1195.136041] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.3 (usb)
KERNEL[1195.136062] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2 (usb)
KERNEL[1195.136082] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2 (usb)
KERNEL[1195.136101] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.3 (usb)
KERNEL[1195.136184] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7 (usb)
KERNEL[1195.136211] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7 (usb)
UDEV  [1195.136861] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/media1 (media)
UDEV  [1195.136958] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/input/input38 (input)
UDEV  [1195.137459] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [1195.138101] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [1195.138538] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [1195.138980] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [1195.140091] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7 (usb)
UDEV  [1195.140982] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7 (usb)
KERNEL[1195.191770] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:1532:0253.0004/input/input31/event25 (input)
UDEV  [1195.192908] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:1532:0253.0004/input/input31/event25 (input)
KERNEL[1195.219711] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:1532:0253.0004/input/input31/input31::numlock (leds)
KERNEL[1195.219739] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:1532:0253.0004/input/input31/input31::numlock (leds)
KERNEL[1195.219751] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:1532:0253.0004/input/input31/input31::capslock (leds)
KERNEL[1195.219761] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:1532:0253.0004/input/input31/input31::capslock (leds)
KERNEL[1195.219777] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:1532:0253.0004/input/input31/input31::scrolllock (leds)
KERNEL[1195.219787] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:1532:0253.0004/input/input31/input31::scrolllock (leds)
UDEV  [1195.221265] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:1532:0253.0004/input/input31/input31::numlock (leds)
UDEV  [1195.221305] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:1532:0253.0004/input/input31/input31::capslock (leds)
UDEV  [1195.221334] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:1532:0253.0004/input/input31/input31::scrolllock (leds)
UDEV  [1195.222155] remove
...
```

I then unbinded and removed both 2-0:1.0 and usb2, however the computer still shows the same error when suspending. I tried hibernating too with systemctl, but the same error comes up.

**Solution**

Okay, managed to fix my problem. I figured that disabling 0000:00:14.0 would be the way to go, nothing else worked. I made a script that runs every time that the computer sleeps and resumes, and placed it in

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep
```

The script contained:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "${1}" == "pre" ]; then
echo 0000:00:14.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind

elif [ "${1}" == "post" ]; then
echo 0000:00:14.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind
fi
```

Comment: Seems like its a hardware problem and needs to be repaired. BTW How do you fry a USB port?

Comment: Check https://askubuntu.com/q/1338682/66509 .

Comment: @N0rbert I've tried those and still no good. Computer still displays the following errors, this is leaving me so frustrated :(