# How do I disable a faulty usb port?

Tags: 20.04, usb, kernel, webcam

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, and my computer has a webcam that has been faulty for a while. On sleep/suspend, I've been seeing a lot of `usb 1-8: device descriptor read/8, error -71` errors. I've looked into `dmesg` output, and it appears that the camera is constantly disconnecting/reconnecting. This is what the `dmesg` output looks like:

```
[  +4.783224] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[  +0.125049] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[  +0.107840] usb usb1-port8: unable to enumerate USB device
[  +0.275899] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 54 using xhci_hcd
[  +5.264005] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  +5.131901] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  +0.232009] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 55 using xhci_hcd
[  +8.888373] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/all, error -71
[  +0.000095] usb usb1-port8: attempt power cycle
[  +0.415538] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 56 using xhci_hcd
[  +4.314715] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=174f, idProduct=2435, bcdDevice= 0.22
[  +0.000004] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  +0.000001] usb 1-8: Product: Integrated Camera
[  +0.000001] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
[  +0.002496] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Camera (174f:2435)
[  +0.006175] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated C as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/input/input51
[  +7.039354] usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 56
[  +0.313458] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 57 using xhci_hcd
```

I think this is also having downstream effects: `lsusb` takes a good ten seconds to run, and usb devices that I plug in sometimes minutes to be recognized. I intend to send this in to get the port itself looked at, but in the meantime, how can I disable the port? I've tried the solutions outlined in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338682/is-it-possible-to-disable-usb-port-with-known-physical-location), but one of the problems is that in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/`, the symlink and folder for the fault usb device sometimes is there, and sometimes isn't, so I can't use the `tee`-based solution, and the `udev` based solution did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to disable USB port with known physical location?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338682/is-it-possible-to-disable-usb-port-with-known-physical-location) I have the same problem, but on 18.04 LTS :)

Comment: @N0rbert Probably not? That is the answer he has linked in his question.

FWIW, I have also this issue, and, at least today, I have not seen any references in lsusb or dmesg to the camera or uvcvideo. I have found that I have a usb1-usb12 (1-12 is the failing port on my machine, a Dell Precision 5530), that is hardwired to the camera. Presumably the camera is not answering at all, so it would be nice if the port doesn't check.

Comment: @N0rbert, I did try the solutions outlined in that post - as @ larsivi points out, it's the one I linked. For a while, this problem didn't seem to be as much of an issue: I think the problematic USB port had become flakier, but all of a sudden, it's back, and those two solutions still don't work :/

Comment: A further update here: it turns out my computer allows disabling USB ports from the BIOS. Disabling the webcam from the BIOS essentially solved all of the problems that I was having - sleep/wakeup is now instantaneous again, apps that depend on the webcam, like Zoom, no longer freeze, `lsusb` is now functional again, and I'm no longer filling up my disk with udev logs.